# woocommerce delete all variations using REST API

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to delete all variations using REST API without passing variation ID. I didn't see any instructions in [wooCommerce REST API doc](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/).

Comment: How about deleting the whole product itself https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#delete-a-product

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using an alternative method. The two requests created in this method. First, to call the product than pass the response variation ID's to another batch request, It will delete all the variations but still there is a limit of maximum 100 variation ID's. It won't delete more than 100 variations in a single request.

If anyone knows the better method, please share.

```
WooCommerce.get("products/794")
  .then((response) => {

WooCommerce.post("products/"+response.data.id+"/variations/batch", response.data.variations)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });


  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned, two rest api requests are required here.

We need to send one to get all the variations of a specific product

```
$response = wp_remote_get(
    "https://your-store/wp-json/wc/v3/products/{$product_id}/variations",
    array(
        'headers' => $headers
    )
);
```

Then we need to get an array of those variations to send it to the batch request:

```
$variations = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
$variations_ids = wp_list_pluck( $variations, 'id' );
```

And then we're sending a batch request:

```
wp_remote_post(
    "https://your-store/wp-json/wc/v3/products/{$product_id}/variations/batch",
    array(
        'headers' => $headers,
        'body' => array( 'delete' => $variations_ids )
    )
);
```

Something like that, the complete code you can find in this tutorial https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/delete-all-product-variations.html